# Migrating Screwturn Wiki content to Sharepoint wiki

Tags: sharepoint, wiki, screwturn

Does anyone know the best way to migrate all my groups screwturn wiki content(pages) over to Sharepoint's wiki?

I can use the  Sharepoint Client API to create a wiki page in sharepoint, so I can read in a screwturn page save it as a Sharepoint page. This works, but I have to do the formatting and that seems like its going to be a real pain in the ***. Can anyone give some advice?